# Using an image from a project folder?

Tags: image, javax.imageio

I'm using the following code to get an image from my pc:

```
imagePez=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Juan Pablo\\Desktop\\pez.png"));
```

but I want to use the images from the project folder so when I export the program it'll show the images on any pc, how can I do that using the `ImageIO.read(new File(.....));`?

Comment: What do you mean by project folder. Do you mean the same folder that you have your source / class files in ?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the images in your project (say `src/main/resources/pez.png`), and use something like:

```
BufferedImage image;

InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pez.png");
try {
     image = ImageIO.read(stream);
}
finally {
    stream.close();
}
```

This will work, regardless of if your project is run from your IDE or if it's packaged in a JAR file.